# Preserving object after a reload scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, reload, scene

In a scene of my quiz game I have an animation object that changes for another animation when a button to move to the next question is pressed (the button reload the scene). I would like to keep the animation, the last animation referenced to the object, after the scene is reloaded, but  I don't know how. The object always returns to its normal state (the first animation).

I currently have a script called 'tower' referenced to the object where I make a static object and a DontDestroyOnLoad function:

```
public static SpriteRenderer towerAnimation;


void Awake()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    towerAnimation = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
}
```

And this code in the Update of 'GameManager' script:

```
public static int counterQuestionChances = 2;

void DestroyTower()
    {
        if (counterQuestionChances == 1)
        {
            Tower.towerAnimation.SetTrigger("error 1");

        }
        else
        {
            if (counterQuestionChances == 0)
            {
                Tower.towerAnimation.SetTrigger("error 2");

            }
        }
```

But it doesn't work. I'm taking shots in the dark because I don't know how to solve this. I'd appreciate if you could give me any ideas that can help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what everything is but don't forget not only does everything get destroyed, it also get re-run.  So your 'GameManager' script will run Awake(), Start(), etc.  therefore Awake() will get called (i.e. DontDestroyOnLoad) too many times. Check this out...https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html.  Next, your animation Triggers will never happen based on your logic.  Also, I wouldn't bother with the static instance of towerAnimation since you're not using it anyway.

Comment: thanks, but I do not know what alternatives I have to preserve the object if I do not use DontDestroyOnLoad. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use the SceneManagement library that Unity has so when the scene changes the method below called OnActiveSceneChanged gets called.

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Tower : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static SpriteRenderer towerAnimation;
    public int storedCounter = 0;
    void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        towerAnimation = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        SceneManager.activeSceneChanged += OnActiveSceneChanged;
    }

    private void OnActiveSceneChanged(UnityEngine.SceneManagement.Scene scene, UnityEngine.SceneManagement.Scene currentScene)
    {
        //tower animation stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: What's exactly does the variable 'storedCounter'? Because I don't see any use in this.

Comment: storing that data between scenes, or atleast keeping that variable somewhere on the script